# on adding radio button in form array previous radio button looses data angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zm6qez?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
```

on adding a row in form array dynamically, my previous radio button looses data but my input field doesn't. However on my pre tag form json value are shown correctly by my HTML not showing

app.component.ts

```
`import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from 
'@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
 name = 'Angular 6';

 constructor(
  private _form:FormBuilder
 ){    
 }

 public form:FormGroup;

 ngOnInit(){
  this.initializeForm();
 }

 public initializeForm(){
  this.form = this._form.group({
  itemRows : this._form.array([this.itemRows()]),
  });   
 }
 public itemRows(){
  return this._form.group({
  name:["",[Validators.required]],
  gender:["male",[Validators.required]]
  });
 }
 public addRow(){    
   const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['itemRows'];
  control.push(this.itemRows());
 }
}`
```

app.component.html

```
`<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
  <div formArrayName="itemRows">
   <div class="row" 
   *ngFor="let item of form.get('itemRows')['controls'];let i=index">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="form-group"  [formGroupName]="i">
      <label for="name_{{i}}">Name</label>
      <input type="text" 
      id="name_{{i}}" 
      formControlName="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"  [formGroupName]="i">
      <label for="gender_{{i}}">Gender</label>
      <input type="radio" id="gender_{{i}}" 
      name="gender"
      formControlName="gender"
      value="male">Male
       <input type="radio" id="gender_{{i}}" 
      name="gender"
      formControlName="gender"
      value="Female">Female
      </div>        
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <button class="button" 
   (click)="addRow()">Add Fields</button>
 </div>
 <pre>
 {{form.value | json}}
 </pre>
</form>`
```

on my HTML pre tag showing clearly what ever data entered data persist but my html radio button showing blank.

Comment: on clicking add button previous  selected radio button goes blank

Comment: now if i add name and select any gender and then i add new row , while selecting 2nd row gender 1st row showing blank....

Comment: Thanks @Krishna Rathore while removing name attribute it works Thankyou!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code

remove `name` attribute from input radio

```
<div class="form-group"  [formGroupName]="i">
      <label for="gender_{{i}}">Gender</label>
      <input type="radio" id="gender_{{i}}"
      formControlName="gender"
      value="male">Male
       <input type="radio" id="gender_{{i}}"
      formControlName="gender"
      value="Female">Female
</div>
```

I have create demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/on-adding-radio-button-in-form-array-previous-radio-button-loos?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are giving the default value as "male" to radio button so when you add new radio control, value of that new control will be selected. So remove the default value "male"

```
public itemRows(){
    return this._form.group({
      name:["",[Validators.required]],
      gender:["",[Validators.required]]
    });
  }
```

Forked [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcq5uj)

Comment: now if i add name and select any gender and then i add new row , while selecting 2nd row gender 1st row showing blank....

Comment: That is probably because all the radio controls have same id. So it is allowing you to select only one

Comment: I think id is changing dynamically id="gender_{{i}}"

Comment: Remove name attribute and check. Probably that is forming the same  group for all radio controls. Check updated demo.

Comment: Thanks @Amit Chigadani while removing name attribute it works Thankyou!!